# Different width for tbody and thead

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML structure from an legacy app I have to style like our new app. For this I need to add margin only for the tbody. So setting padding in table won't work because the header should be as wide as the table.

Here's a little sketch what it should look like:
[image]

Why do I need that? I have to put two tables side by side and it should look like as there is only one header but two content tables.

I played around with padding and borders of the thead element but the problem is that the thead has a bottom border which isn't applied to the right border.

**Edit:/**
The picture is about what I want. The two tables are mentioned because that's the reason I want one table to look like that.

Solutions are welcome if they style the table like I showed in the picture or style two tables with two different tbodys and theads like they would have one thead.

What I need are still correct labels for the columns in tbody but the left and the right column should be a little bit wider to stretch it to the whole table.

**Edit:/**
Because there was some confusion what I meant here is a screenshot of the style I want to accomplish without altering the DOM structure with JS:
[image]

Comment: The text “I have to put two tables side by side and it should look like as there is only one header but two content tables” does not really explain what you are doing. The picture has only one table.

Comment: Why would you use a table if you definitely do not want a fundamental feature of a table: all rows being of equal width?

Comment: Your text says "two tables side by side", but I don't see that in your drawing at all.

Comment: Right. The picture shows what one table should look like. And the reason why I would something like that is because I have to put two of them side by side. (See my update)

BUT: that's a valid question, why close it?

Comment: If you vote for close, elaborate at least why. How should I improve my question if you don't give me pointers what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `display:table` to `tbody` and use custom width for that easily.

[**Complete Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/J4qbE/4/)

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Head1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Head2</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
table{
    width: 500px;
background: #808080;
}
thead{
    width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background: #FF6347;
}
tbody{
    display: table;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
background: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I transformed your code to a example similar to my code and it breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/J4qbE/1/

Comment: @schlingel look at complete demo added to answer.

Comment: @schlingel is it ok buddy ? `:)`

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect a solution that complete! Tank you

Answer (score -1):

your calendar is actually two subtables (including a header with day names). from that point of view, using two cells with padding on the outer table would give you the desired effect

Comment: I want a CSS only solution. Restructuring the DOM via JS does already work - as you can see.